# Is "vindicate" a form of "indicate"

Tags: etymology

The [online dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=indicate&searchmode=none) has the following to say:

> Indicate >> to point out, show...
>
> Vindicate >> to clear from censure or doubt by means of demonstration...

"Showing" is a means of "demonstrating" so is it reasonable to believe that "vindicate" is a form of "indicate?"

The word "re-enter" is derived from the preposition "re" and the root word "enter." What preposition (if any) would be represented by the "v" in "vindicate"? If there is none, how would the "v" cause "vindicate" to be a form of "indicate."

Comment: Looking in etymonline shows that *vindication* [came from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=vindication&searchmode=none) vim + dicere: to say by force. And *indication* [came from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=indication&searchmode=none) in + dicere: to say upon. (And of course, *diction* came from dicere.)

Comment: @PeterShor: OK, you looked at the problem from a DIFFERENT angle, and came up with your conclusion. Very interesting. If you made your comment into an answer, I'd probably upvote it.

Comment: You can't tell how words are actually related by their meanings in dictionaries. Only etymologies can tell you the real history.

Comment: @JohnLawler: My understanding is that etyonline is a DUAL purpose tool. Or is it?

Comment: I have no idea; I rarely use it. You'd have to consult them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are related in that they both came from the Latin word *dicere*, meaning "to say". Etymonline shows that [vindication](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=vindication&searchmode=none) comes from *vim* + *dicere*, whose roots mean something like "to say with force". And [indication](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=indication&searchmode=none) comes from *in* + *dicere*, whose roots mean something like "to say upon". So the prefix for *vindication* is *vim,* not *v-* (and it technically is a word and not a prefix; *vindication* is a compound word, and not prefix + word).